# Get name of outputFileNameMapping in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-plugin

I'm building a maven project which is using the assembly plugin for packaging in a jenkins pipeline. Within package.xml I've set the outputFileNameMapping to:

```
    <dependencySet>
    ...
<outputFileNameMapping>${artifact.artifactId}-${artifact.version}.${artifact.extension} </outputFileNameMapping>
    ...

    </dependencySet>
```

so the final file is name like myproject-34.0-SNAPSHOT-bin.tar.gz

After the build I want to upload the file to a fileserver. Is there a variable which contains the whole filename after the build?

Comment: You can read the pom.xml file within Jenkins pipeline and create file on your own because in Jenkins is no such variable as far as I know...

Comment: OK, at least I get the artifactId and version from the pom. In this case I can hardcode  the '-bin.tar.gz' part of the filename and I can concatenate all together.